# Is boundedness conserved under equivalent metrics?

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Let (X,$\rho$) be a general metric space where $\rho$ is a bounded metric, that is, $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall x,y\in X$ $\rho(x,y)<M$. Now let $\sigma$ be a metric equivalent to $\rho$. Must $\sigma$ be a bounded metric?

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi Not true.  There is even an example on that page that disproves the claim (in the contrapositive).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the correction, maybe next time I'll have to look at it with more detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For instance, $d(x,y) = |\tan^{-1}(x) - \tan^{-1}(y)|$ is a bounded metric on $\mathbb R$ that generates the standard topology.